# How do i add shadow or bottom margin in dropdownlist in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to add shadow or margin to the bottom of text so user can see distinctly different tiles in it. How do i go about that?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the text as a child to a `Container` and then set it's border according to your need.

```
DropdownMenuItem(
  child: Container(
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
        SizedBox(
          width: 8,
        ),
        Text('Logout'),
      ],
    ),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
        bottom: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.black87,
          width: 1.0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[Dartpad link](https://dartpad.dev/fa101d7d2f1a9adc86eb7b9e695647f8). Output:

[image: Shows a dropdown list item with bottom border]

Comment: I have done the same but the length of border is only until the text length. I kind of need to expand it to full length

Comment: I investigated it a bit and it turns out DropdownMenuItem always adds some padding to it's child and I couldn't find any way to remove it. Maybe it's in accordance to Material design. I have updated the link.

Comment: Solved this issue by wrapping it in a column. Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure how to show it here. Just aligned the text in the middle and wrapped the dropdown into a column

Comment: just post it as the answer